# Laravel get products by passing id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an array of products id, i have to fetch all the products belonging to that id

```
{
    "products":[1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

in my controller

```
public function productsCart(Request $request) 
{
    //dd($request->products);

    foreach ($request->products as $key => $product) {

        $product = Product::where('id', $product[0])->get();

    }

    return Response::json($product);
}
```

i'm getting empty array as response

thank you

Comment: Isn't your object been overwritten? replace with `foreach ($request->products as $productId) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
public function productsCart(Request $request) 
{
    $products = Product::whereIn('id', $request->products)->get();

    return Response::json($products);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, this gives me only one product, i want all the products belongs to the `id` in the `product` array

Comment: This fetches all the ids given in this array `$request->products`. Check if the ids in this array are correct and exists inside the table

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereIn`

```
public function productsCart(Request $request) 
{
    $products = Product::whereIn('id', $request->products)->get();

    return Response::json($products);
}
```

or if you want to loop then

```
foreach ($request->products as $id) {

        $product[] = Product::where('id', $id)->get();

    }
```